# Deserializing nested collection in XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization

I am getting some XML from a web service, but it is not deserializing the way I want it to. I want to have a collection of Row elements, where each has a collection of Value elements.  However, the deserialized object only captures the last Row element in the XML. Here are the classes:

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class SimpleCodeList
    {
        [XmlArray("rowField")]
        private SimpleCodeListValue[] rowField;

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Value", IsNullable = false)]
        public SimpleCodeListValue[] Row
        {
            get
            {
                return this.rowField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.rowField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class SimpleCodeListValue
    {

        private string simpleValueField;

        private string columnRefField;

        public string SimpleValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this.simpleValueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.simpleValueField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string ColumnRef
        {
            get
            {
                return this.columnRefField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.columnRefField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the XML:

```
<CodeList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="...">
    <ColumnSet xmlns="">
        <Column Id="code" Use="required">
            <ShortName>Code</ShortName>
            <Data Type="normalizedString" Lang="en" />
        </Column>
        <Column Id="name" Use="optional">
            <ShortName>Name</ShortName>
            <Data Type="normalizedString" Lang="en" />
        </Column>
    </ColumnSet>
    <SimpleCodeList xmlns="">
        <Row>
            <Value ColumnRef="code">
                <SimpleValue>1234</SimpleValue>
            </Value>
            <Value ColumnRef="name">
                <SimpleValue>Service 123</SimpleValue>
            </Value>            
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Value ColumnRef="code">
                <SimpleValue>5678</SimpleValue>
            </Value>
            <Value ColumnRef="name">
                <SimpleValue>Service 456</SimpleValue>
            </Value>            
        </Row>
     ...
```

Could some one please correct me if my classes are correct corresponding to the given XML? Thank you.

Update:
I am using the following codes to deserialize the xml.

First I convert the xml string into an XmlDocument:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(responseFromServer);
```

Then run it through this function:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(XmlDocument doc)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc);
    using (reader)
    {
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }            
}
...
CodeList codelist = Utility.Deserialize<CodeList>(xml);
```

I can see through inspecting the XmlDocument that there are over 100 elements, but the 'codelist' object only contains 1 of those.

Comment: Have you looked into [xml2csharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net)? You can paste your code there to get all the classes you would need.

Comment: I used the paste special feature in visual studio to generate the classes.

Comment: How are you deserializing the xml and where do you see it's only last element

Comment: I've updated the question.  When I paste the xml into notepad++, I can see that the row stored in the 'codelist' object is the last row in the pasted xml.

Comment: Can please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?  You're missing the definition for the `CodeList` type.  I made a sample fiddle from your code here https://dotnetfiddle.net/n3Y1P3, but it has a compilation error `Compilation error (line 96, col 35): The type or namespace name 'CodeList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: You need to replace XmlArrayItemAttribute with XmlElement for "array" items.  When you use  XmlArrayItemAttribute serialization expects two elements : NODES and NODE.   When you use XmlElement serialize only requires one element NODE.